# How to get sum along with this Laravel Eloquent query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

**Database Structure:**
**Table:** sales_payments
**columns:** id, payer_id, payment_status, amount , ...

Please see this eloquent query. it's working fine but now i need the sum of amount key along with this given eloquent query and where conditions.

```
    $query =  SalesPayment::with(['abc.xyz'])

        ->whereHas('abc.xyz', function ($query) use ($options) {
            $query->where('xyz_id',$options['xyz_id']);
        });

    $query->where(['key3' => key3(), 'payment_status' => PAYMENT_STATUS_SUCCESS]);
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    return $query->paginate(config('constants.PAGE_LIMIT'));
```

**Possible Solution**

Just put a select as mentioned below

```
$query =  SalesPayment::select('*', \DB::raw('SUM(amount) AS total_sale_amount')->with ....
```

I have tested this solution it's working fine.

Please let me know if there is a better solution than this. And I'm looking for some other solutions Also.

**Edit:** But there is one problem with this solution that it returning me only one record when i put aggregate function (sum) in select otherwise it was returning more than one records.

Comment: Yeah! this is perfect

Comment: @YasinPatel But there is one problem with this solution that it returning me only one record when i put aggregate function (sum) in select otherwise it was returning more than one records.

Comment: seems like a good. you can get table sum of the column along with a table records

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `sum` method on the query.

```
$amount = $query->sum('amount');
```

A new query with the same conditions will be executed to calculate the sum of a column.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#aggregates

Comment: but it will execute 2 separate queries at the database end

Comment: Thats true, I don't know another solution. But in your case I think you have to use 2 queries because you use paginate. I assume you want the total amount of all pages, but only select the rows for the current page,